# How disable image attachment pages in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to disable image attachment pages in my WordPress site as it the images are stumbling my rankings. I did a research and found I can do it by implementing a code in my image.php file instead of installing a plugin.

I really need your help as I don't know where to place the code in the image.php file.

The code I want to add: `<?php wp_redirect(get_permalink($post->post_parent)); ?>`

My image.php file:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying image attachments.
 *
 * @package sparkling
 */

get_header();
?>

            <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                <div class="post-inner-content">
                    <article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>
                        <header class="entry-header">
                            <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>

                            <div class="entry-meta">
                                <?php sparkling_posted_on(); ?>
                            </div><!-- .entry-meta -->

                            <nav role="navigation" id="image-navigation" class="navigation-image nav-links">
                                <div class="nav-previous"><?php previous_image_link( false, __( '<i class="fa fa-chevron-left"></i> Previous', 'sparkling' ) ); ?></div>
                                <div class="nav-next"><?php next_image_link( false, __( 'Next <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>', 'sparkling' ) ); ?></div>
                            </nav><!-- #image-navigation -->
                        </header><!-- .entry-header -->

                        <div class="entry-content">

                            <div class="entry-attachment">
                                <div class="attachment">
                                    <?php
                                        /**
                                         * Grab the IDs of all the image attachments in a gallery so we can get the URL of the next adjacent image in a gallery,
                                         * or the first image (if we're looking at the last image in a gallery), or, in a gallery of one, just the link to that image file
                                         */
                                        $attachments = array_values( get_children( array(
                                            'post_parent'    => $post->post_parent,
                                            'post_status'    => 'inherit',
                                            'post_type'      => 'attachment',
                                            'post_mime_type' => 'image',
                                            'order'          => 'ASC',
                                            'orderby'        => 'menu_order ID'
                                        ) ) );
                                        foreach ( $attachments as $k => $attachment ) {
                                            if ( $attachment->ID == $post->ID )
                                                break;
                                        }
                                        $k++;
                                        // If there is more than 1 attachment in a gallery
                                        if ( count( $attachments ) > 1 ) {
                                            if ( isset( $attachments[ $k ] ) )
                                                // get the URL of the next image attachment
                                                $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $attachments[ $k ]->ID );
                                            else
                                                // or get the URL of the first image attachment
                                                $next_attachment_url = get_attachment_link( $attachments[ 0 ]->ID );
                                        } else {
                                            // or, if there's only 1 image, get the URL of the image
                                            $next_attachment_url = wp_get_attachment_url();
                                        }
                                    ?>

                                    <a href="<?php echo $next_attachment_url; ?>" title="<?php the_title_attribute(); ?>" rel="attachment"><?php
                                        $attachment_size = apply_filters( 'sparkling_attachment_size', array( 1200, 1200 ) ); // Filterable image size.
                                        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $post->ID, $attachment_size );
                                    ?></a>
                                </div><!-- .attachment -->

                                <?php if ( ! empty( $post->post_excerpt ) ) : ?>
                                <div class="entry-caption">
                                    <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                                </div><!-- .entry-caption -->
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div><!-- .entry-attachment -->

                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                            <?php
                                wp_link_pages( array(
                                    'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'sparkling' ),
                                    'after'  => '</div>',
                                ) );
                            ?>

                        </div><!-- .entry-content -->

                        <footer class="entry-meta">
                        </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
                    </article><!-- #post-<?php the_ID(); ?> -->
                </div>
                <?php
                    // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template
                    if ( comments_open() || '0' != get_comments_number() )
                        comments_template();
                ?>

            <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: a redirect isn't going to help anything. if images are causing a problem, you  shouldn't be using images at all. putting a redirect in there will just send the user off to some other page, which is probably not what you want.

Comment: I need to use images. The redirect will be to the post page and if their is no post page he will be returned to the home page.

Answer (score 2):

Place the snippet below into `theme/image.php`. It includes the fallback you need in order to redirect the end user to the home page (or any other page) in the event that no parent post page can be found.
This happens when media items are uploaded directly to the media library rather than through a post or page.

```
<?php
global $post;
if ( $post && $post->post_parent ) {
    wp_redirect( get_permalink( $post->post_parent ), 301 );
} else {
    wp_redirect( home_url( '/' ), 301 );    
}
exit;
```

Comment: But where should it be placed? I'm also unsure about this.

Comment: @poepje `image.php`

Comment: I get that, but where in this file? Placing it at the top doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @poepje You would typically find it in the root of the theme folder. But if it don't you may have to do a bit of googling with the theme in question to locate it - or create your own.

Comment: I appreciate the help, but you didn't read my question right. I know which file, and where to find this. What I asked is, where in this file do I place the code so that it will work?

Comment: @poepje Silly me, my apologies. Placing the code snippet at the top should work. Do you have the file child themed? How are you testing it?

Comment: I tried it at the top but it doesn't work. It's on a live SSH server. Everything else works normally.

Comment: Try the bottom then, you could have code below it that, for whatever reason (I can only assume) is negating the code above. I'm also assuming you are navigating to the attachment page of the image that you expect to be redirecting, either to the parent post page or home page (or otherwise whatever page you've specified in the event that there is no parent post page to redirect to)? Have you got the theme child-themed? If so, verify that there is no `image.php` in that child theme directory that isn't overwriting the `image.php` in the parent theme directory.